# Running event for longer period

Tags: c#

Would running the event Timer elapsed under a longer period of time cause reduced system performance?

I ran it for 5 minutes and it seemed to steadily use 21MB process memory

such as below:

```
    private static Timer aTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        aTimer = new Timer(2000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed event happend at {0}", e.SignalTime);
        Process[] nProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCESSNAME");
        if (nProcess.Length > 0)
        {
            nProcess[0].Kill();
            Console.WriteLine("Process {0} has been terminated", nProcess);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you do not perform heavy operations then no. It wont reduce performance.

Comment: If I would perform heavy operations what would you recommend then? or is there no way around it?

Comment: don't mess with GC please. remove this line `GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);` and use System.Timers.Timer

Comment: It depends. If you want some make some heavy but continous operation then i would recommend making some sub-process and redirect IO making some pipeline or make some thread that can be easily killed by your main application.

Comment: You have an event that runs every 2 seconds with very little code in the event.  Should not effect performance.

Comment: @m.rogalski Alright seems fair enough, I'll probably stick to light continous operations atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not cause any significant performance impact. The callback allocated to the timer keeps the program alive. The GetProcessesByName function called on timedevent will allocate additional process space into the array but I assume it will still be insignificant considering the overall process memory space.